# Showing multiple notification messages with single id

Tags: android

I have several events which happen at the same time. I need to display multiple notification messages to user in serial way.

The ideal case is, each notification message will take turn to show up, for around 2 seconds.

The closest I can get is using multiple id. However, using multiple id has a side effect which I do not want. It will end up with multiple notification messages shown at status bar at the same time.

**This makes user's status clutter, which is not my intention.**

### Using multiple ids (End up with multiple clutter messages shown)

```
int id = 0;
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getActivity())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("MyApp")
            .setTicker(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentText(message);
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(id++, mBuilder.build());   
}
```

However, if I do not use multiple id, but using single id, ***only 1 message will be shown, if several notification requests were made at the same time. every message will take turn to show up. no message lost.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create my own message queuing system. Not using single id, but able to achieve what I want

***only 1 message will be shown, if several notification requests were made at the same time. every message will take turn to show up. no message lost.***

`this.blockingQueue.offer(message);`

Here is the complete message queuing system.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    executor.submit(new NotificationTask());
}

private class NotificationTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!executor.isShutdown()) {
            try {
                String message = blockingQueue.take();
                notification(message);
                // Allow 5 seconds for every message.
                Thread.sleep(Constants.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_LIFE_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "", ex);
                // Error occurs. Stop immediately.
                break;
            }                
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Will be triggered during back button pressed.
    super.onDestroy();
    executor.shutdownNow();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", ex);
    }
}

private void notification(String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getActivity())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setTicker(message)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    // Do we need to have sound effect?

    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final int id = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new NotificationManagerCancelRunnable(mNotificationManager, id), Constants.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_LIFE_TIME);
}

// Use static class, to avoid memory leakage.
private static class NotificationManagerCancelRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private final int id;

    public NotificationManagerCancelRunnable(NotificationManager notificationManager, int id) {
        this.notificationManager = notificationManager;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        notificationManager.cancel(id);
    }
}

// For notification usage. 128 is just a magic number.
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private final BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(128);
private final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need only one `Notification` in the status bar, but you want the message to indicate all of your app's notifications, then you need to manage the single `Notification` by changing the message.

Every time you repost the `Notification` with `sendNotification(message)`, the `Notification` `ticker` text will be updated.

For example, if you have a single notification of an item in your hypothetical inbox, you can post a message like this:

> Message from Joe.

When you receive multiple new messages, change it to:

> You have (n) messages.

When the user presses the `Notification`, you should redirect to an `Activity` that displays everything in something like a `ListView` or `GridView`, to display all of your *messages*.

Comment: My displayed information is series of stock alert message (either rise above price or fall below price). Hence, if there are 20 stocks, i need to display 20 messages in turn, in serial fashion, with every message shown up for 5 seconds.