# sending notifications with alarmmanager and Broadcast receiver

Tags: android

Actually I have implemented notifications for my app.Whenever I click a button it set the time for notification and call broadcast receiver.but when the request for 3 notifications like one for 3 pm,4 pm,5 pm is sent it send only 5 pm notification not 3 pm and 4 pm because 5 pm one was triggered last. I think it is related with notification id. I am passing id as 0.what I should do.please help.

my broadcast receiver

```
public class NotificationMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Log.d("Tag","dd");
        showNotification(context);
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        Log.d("Tag", "visible");

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setContentTitle("HURRY UP!!")
                        .setContentText("You have a session in 15 minutes.");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int notiid = preferences.getInt("Id", -1 );

        int notification_id = notiid;
        Log.d("ID1", String.valueOf(notification_id));

        mNotificationManager.notify(notification_id, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d("Tag","fuck u");
    }
}
```

this is where I am calling:

```
holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                Call<AcceptedDealResponse> call = service.acceptedDeal(acceptDealRequest);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<AcceptedDealResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AcceptedDealResponse> call, Response<AcceptedDealResponse> response) {
                        AcceptedDealResponse response1 = response.body();
                        if(response.body().getMessage().equals("Successful !! Deal Booked !!")){
                            Log.d(",,", "" + " deal boooked");


                            Log.d("jkhdjksahda  ","" + newDealResponsess.getResponses().get(position).getTimeFrom() );


                            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                            try {
                                date1 = formatter.parse(String.valueOf(newDealResponsess.getResponses().get(position).getTimeFrom()));

                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.setTime(date1);

                            Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)));


                            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
                            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));

                            Log.d("hdfbsdhbfs :", "" + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                            Log.d("hdfbsdhbfs :", "" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                            Log.d("hdfbsdhbfs :", "" + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                            Log.d("hdfbsdhbfs :", "" + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
                            Log.d("hdfbsdhbfs :", "" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                            Log.d("hdfbsdhbfs :", "" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

                            Intent notificationmassage = new Intent(v.getContext(),NotificationMessage.class);

                            Log.d("Tag","cool");

                            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), 0,notificationmassage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                            Log.d("Tag","cooled");
                            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                            Log.d("Tag","cooooled");

                            int id = (int) calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(v.getContext());
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putInt("Id", id);
                            Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(id));
                            editor.apply();


                            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (calendar.getTimeInMillis() - 900000), pi);
```

Comment: yes add different ids it will work

Comment: `I think it is related with notification id` you are right. `I am passing id as 0` then it overwrites the notification with this ID every time. `what I should do` use different IDs

Comment: how to use them that is the question@Pravin

Comment: how to pass different ids that is the question @VladMatvienko

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953195/showing-multiple-notification-messages-with-single-id)

Comment: don't use `0`, use `1`,`2`, etc. Store the last used number, and pass `lastUsedNumber++`

Comment: not helping @VladMatvienko  now i am sending different ids but still not working is there any other thing I should be aware of

Comment: then you do it incorrectly. But since you didn't show your code, nobody can tell you what is the problem.

Comment: I have added my code now see please I am having this problem from long time please do help @VladMatvienko

Comment: you don't use different notification IDs in your code. Also you should use different IDs for the AlarmManager as well

Comment: Please explain I am not getting @VladMatvienko

Comment: In the code you don't show that you use different notification IDs.

Comment: now see the full code and tell me @VladMatvienko

Comment: ok, now I see that you use id 0 in your `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), 0,notificationmassage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`, which also has to be different not to relpace the AlarmManager events. That's why I've asked for the code.

Comment: let me try and get back to u btw thank u @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is in your `PendingIntent` with same `REQUEST_CODE`. May be you have used same `REQUEST_CODE` with your `PendingInetent` for all `alarm` when setting an `alarm` using AlarmManager.

> Try using different `REQUEST_CODE` for different `PendingIntent` for
>   different `Alarm`.

**Use below code for setting `Alarm` using `AlarmManager`:**

```
    int notiId = UNIQUE_ID;

    // Intent
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationMessage.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", notiId);

    // Pending broadcast intent
    PendingIntent mPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 
                        notiId, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Alarm manager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, TARGET_TIME_MILLISECONDS, mPI);
```

Hope this will work~